# Wrong alphabetic order for Norwegian bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting, scandinavian-letters

In Norwegian, `aa` is an (obsolete) alternative spelling of `å`, but it is still very commonly used in names. In bibliographies, it should as a result be alphabetized as if it said `å` (cf. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85#Place_in_alphabet)). In `biblatex`, however, it is alphabetized under `a`. How can I fix this? In the MWE below, the entry `Aasen` should in fact follow `Årst`, since `Aasen` should be treated as `Åsen`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}
\usepackage[style = authoryear, language = nynorsk]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{aasen1864,
    AUTHOR = "Ivar Aasen",
    TITLE = "Norsk Grammatik",
    YEAR = "1864"}
@book{aarst2010,
    AUTHOR = "Ole Martin Årst",
    TITLE = "Playing soccer is cool!",
    YEAR = "2010"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any occurrences of `aa` that are *not* replacements of `å`? (You might get into trouble with `Aachen`/`Aabenraa` thingy mentioned in Wikipedia.) Your best bet is probably manually using `sortname`. Copy-pasting the `author` to `sortname` and replacing `aa` with `å` can be done with Biber's mapping features, but this will sort `Aachen` under `Åchen` (probably wrong) and might not work particularly well if you play around with `useauthor=false` a bit. (I'm not sure whether the upcoming multiscript version 3.0 of `biblatex` could be of any help here).

Comment: @moewe If a Scandinavian name begins in ``Aa-``, it should always be alphabetized as ``Å-``. If there's a foreign name beginning in ``Aa-``, it should not (Aachen and Aabenraa are cities, btw, and wouldn't appear in a bibliography). I guess that would apply to Finnish names like ``Paavo Aaltonen``. So you might be right that using ``sortname`` is the way to go here.

Comment: But actually, using ``sortname = Ivar Åsen`` doesn't yield the correct result either, because ``biblatex`` will treat ``Å`` as a kind of ``A``. I will open a new question about this.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer here: http://heim.ifi.uio.no/dag/latex-links/biblatex-guide.pdf. I need to add ``sortlocale = nb_NO``.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding `sortlocale = nn_NO` (`nn` for Norwegian nynorsk, `nb` for Norwegian bokmål) as a package option will ensure that `Aa` is treated as `Å`, *and* that `Å` is alphabetized last. Cf. the University of Oslo’s [Local guide to `biblatex`](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/dag/latex-links/biblatex-guide.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}
\usepackage[style = authoryear, language = nynorsk, sortlocale = nn_NO]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{aasen1864,
    AUTHOR = "Ivar Aasen",
    TITLE = "Norsk Grammatik",
    YEAR = "1864"}
@book{aarst2010,
    AUTHOR = "Ole Martin Årst",
    TITLE = "Playing soccer is cool!",
    YEAR = "2010"}
@book{lennon1975,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "I like to play the guitar",
    YEAR = "1975"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

With the current version of [`biber`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biber) (version 2.10), `sortlocale` will automatically be set by the command `\setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}` from `polyglossia`, cf. [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408011/bibliography-order-how-to-get-danish-letters-%c3%a6-%c3%b8-%c3%a5-last#comment1017852_408018). It is therefore no longer necessary to add an explicit `sortlocale = nn_NO` as a `biblatex` option. That is, one can replace the line

```
\usepackage[style = authoryear, language = nynorsk, sortlocale = nn_NO]
```

from the MWE above with

```
\usepackage[style = authoryear, language = nynorsk]{biblatex}
```

and get the same result.

Comment: That guide will  be a very useful resource for anyone trying to get to grips with Biblatex.

Comment: Due to bugs (?), this solution does not work with the current versions of `biblatex` and `biber`, cf. [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263900/sortlocale-no-longer-works-with-current-versions-of-biblatex-and-biber).

Comment: On my system (Biber 2.7, MikTeX on Win 10) I get the correct sorting even with `\usepackage[style = authoryear]{biblatex}` without explicitly setting `language = nynorsk, sortlocale = nn_NO`. Does that also work for you?

Comment: @moewe No, I don't. I get the order Årst-Aasen-Lennon instead of Lennon-Årst-Aasen. Biber 2.7. Biblatex version 3.7. Tex live 2017.

Comment: Oh, blast. I hoped this would be corrected with TeX live. Is the order correct with `sortlocale = nn_NO`?

Comment: @moewe Sigh, no. The MWE above no longer produces the correct sorting. So https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263900/sortlocale-no-longer-works-with-current-versions-of-biblatex-and-biber is once again valid `:(`

Comment: I suspect this is due to an outdated version of a Perl library Biber uses, but can't be sure. Do you have a bit of time to investigate this? If so, could you run Biber in trace mode (`biber --trace testfile`) and check what versions is reported in the (massive) `.blg` under `locale_version`? Mine is `1.1.19`, if you have `1.14` or lower that would be bad.

Comment: Biber 2.8 is now out in TeX live 2017 and MikTeX. On my machine the sorting is as expected now. Even without `language = nynorsk, sortlocale = nn_NO`. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @moewe I'll check later this week.

Comment: It would be nice if you could check if things work out of the box (i.e., without `sortlocale`) for you in never Biber versions (>=2.8, current is 2.10). If so it would be nice if you could edit your answer to remove the unnecessary lines (or mention that `sortlocale` is not needed here thanks to auto-detection and only necessary if the locale must be explicitly overridden https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408011/35864).

Comment: @moewe Done! Sorry about my late action - I've been away from stack exchange for quite some time.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. In fact the `language = nynorsk` will also be inferred automatically, so it should not be necessary either.

Comment: @moewe When I remove `language = nynorsk`, I see this in my log file: `Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'nynorsk'... Package biblatex Info: ... file 'nynorsk.lbx' found.` Is that the basis for saying that it infers `nynorsk` automatically from the `polyglossia` setting?

Comment: @Sverre You should also see that if you have `language=nynorsk` in your preamble. It definitely shows that the right thing is going on. The basis for my hint was this passage from the `biblatex` docs: "Note that `biblatex` automatically adjusts to the main document language if `babel` or `polyglossia` is loaded."  (and other passages as well). I will admit though, that there is a difference if you use a different `autolang` setting.