# sortlocale no longer works with current versions of biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

With the most recent versions of [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (v. 3.0) and [`biber`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber) (v. 2.1), the `sortlocale` option has no longer any effect.

[This code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164763/9077), then, will no longer produce the correctly sorted Norwegian bibliography.

[image]

This smells like a bug, but I'm not allowed to submit bug reports either for [`biblatex`](https://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/bugs/) or [`biber`](https://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex-biber/bugs/), so I'm posting this here in the hope that either (1) someone who *can* submit bug reports will, or (2) a work-around can be appplied.

Comment: With the development version biber 2.2 Lennon is again at the first place. Perhaps it is the same problem as in this issue (which is resolved in the dev too) https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/78

Comment: Even though there's no bug tracker enabled, you can email the maintainer(s) with bug reports.  And bug reports per se are off topic. [Questions which are bug reports](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2622)

Comment: I just checked, with Biber 2.2 (beta) (currently available as developer version via sourceforge) the sorting looks like the [desired one again](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164763/35864). So I'm voting to close as off topic. (BTW: Why aren't you allowed to open a bug report? This site here isn't really your bug report-y site.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a problem (bug?) fixed in a newer version of the software.

Comment: @moewe I was aware of the problem of this being a bug report, that's why I also asked for a possible work-around. No idea why I can't submit a bug report - can you? I was able to submit one to plk's GitHub, though. With `biber 2.2` fixing the issue, I agree this should be closed.

Comment: I should think so yes. Bugs/Issues are currently managed at github as far as I'm aware so that should be fine. Where did you initially want to submit to? (The doc says "Biber's git repository and bug/feature tracker is on github (https://github.com/plk/biber).", so I assume that is the official channel).

Comment: @moewe I tried where the links in my question lead you. That's what came up when I googled for biber, biblatex, and bug reports.

Comment: Ah OK, I don't think the sourceforge bug trackers are in active use any more. Development takes place over at github and release as well as some testing versions of `biblatex` and Biber are then pushed over to sourceforge.

Comment: For completeness sake, I'm letting you know that this bug is reintroduced in the current version of `biber`: `biber` v.2.7, `biblatex` v.3.7, `tex live 2017`.

Comment: Biber 2.8 and `biblatex` 3.8a are out now in TeX live 2017 and MikTeX. The problem should be solved with an update to those versions. In my tests things worked as expected with those versions on MikTeX (Win 10) and TeX live (Ubuntu 17.10).