# Sort "aa" as an "å" using biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting, scandinavian-letters

[image]
Currently I'm writing a project in Danish. Almost everything in LaTeX works as intended so far.

However, in the Danish language "aa" is alphabetically the same as an "å", and should therefore be sorted last in the bibliography, instead of first as an "a".

Hope some smart mind knows how to force LaTeX to sort "aa" as an "å".

Updated info: OS: Windows 10, client: ShareLaTeX, biber version is unknown.

Is there any reason why a "G", "K" and "S" is sorted before both "Aa" and "Å"?

MWE from the project:

```
\usepackage[
backend = biber,
style = authoryear,
natbib = true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

@online{aalborgkommune16,
author = {{Aalborg Kommune}},
title = {Team Vandkunstens forslag til udviklingsplan valgt som det bedste},
year = {2016},
url = {https://stigsborghavnefront.dk/nyheder?id=28},
urldate = {2017-10-11}
}
```

Comment: Your MWE will be always sorted... and this means it is more minimal than have to be... Also it is not a working example. Please use filecontents etc to create a real MWE

Comment: Maybe this question and its answers help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164758/134144

Comment: What version of Biber are you running (check `biber --version`)? What distribution do you use (MikTeX/TeX live)? On what system (Linux/Windows)? It will be easier for us to check what is going on if you can provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows the problem immediately when we compile it. We need to know about your language settings (`babel`, `polyglossia`). Please also show the `.blg` file (it will contain info about the sorting.).

Comment: I just did a short test. On my system (Biber 2.7 on MikTeX, Win 10) a document with `\usepackage[danish]{babel}` sorts "aa" as "å". Please compile https://gist.github.com/moewew/50d462052893cb7037f0c280788cad6a and report the output along with the answer to the questions in my comment above. Could be related: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/164

Comment: I have updated the required information, and tested with moewe's recommended github link. How come a "G", "S", "K" etc. is  sorted after both "Aa" and "Å"?

Comment: Please tell us your Biber version, your OS and the TeX distribution you use. Can you also add a picture of the output you get from the linked MWE?

Comment: I am using sharelatex, hence I don't know my biber or tex distribution. My OS is Windows 10.  I have added a picture in the post above, in which you can see, that the bibliography is not alphabetically sorted.

Comment: Sharelatex are using an outdated version of Biber, but even with the current version of Biber there were problems in Linux and Mac OS X. The developer has addressed some of them, but a new version has not been released yet.

Comment: You will have to use a workaround such as `sortname = {{zzzAalborg Kommune}}` in the meantime.

Comment: Biber 2.8/`biblatex` 3.8a are now out. But I'm not sure when ShareLaTeX will update.

Answer (score 3):

There was a problem with sorting locales in Biber <= 2.7 in TeX live. This was resolved with Biber 2.8 (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/164), the current release version is 2.10. It should be enough to update your TeX system.

In the comments it emerged that you use ShareLaTeX. Online LaTeX editors can in general not be expected to be on the bleeding edge of CTAN package development. At the moment ShareLaTeX are running Biber 2.7, Overleaf has version 2.5.

If you are stuck with the online editors you will need a work-around. Since the problem is quite deep in Biber's internals we'll have to resort to ad hoc trickery.

```
sortname = {{zzzAalborg Kommune}}
```

Will make sure that `Aalborg` sorts after `z`.