# Biblatex (biber) sortlocale=se sorting Å as F

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

I can't get the swedish character Å to sort correctly. (It should be A-ZÅÄÖ), I have attached code that should display the issue:
Edit: I am using sharelatex.com, and would prefer if it was solvable within that ecosystem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,sorting = nyt,sortlocale=se]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Hello \parencite{Ahlstrom} \parencite{gillham2008} \parencite{eupopulation}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

References.bib:

```
@online{eupopulation,
    author = "{Eurostat}",
    title = "Population structure and ageing",
    date = "2018-01-12",
    addendum ="(Hämtad 2018-02-04)"

}
@incollection{Ahlstrom,
    author = "Pär Åhlström",
    title = "Human Relations: Elton Mayo \& the Hawthorne Investigations",
    booktitle = "Industriell Verksamhetsutveckling",
    publisher = "Göteborg: Chalmers tekniska högskola",
    editor = "Magnus Persson",
    year = "2016",
    keywords  = "hawthorne",
    pages = "71-74",
}
@book{gillham2008,
    author = "Bill Gillham",
    title = "Forskningsintervjun: Tekniker och genomförande",
    translator = "Emily Jamison Gromark",
    shorttitle = "Forskningsintervjun",
    publisher = "Studentlitteratur",
    year = "2004",
    keywords = "Forskningsintervjun",
    ISBN = "978-91-44-04012-7"
}
```

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ? And, even more importantly, which version of `biblatex` and which version of `biber` do you use? On my MacTeX2017 system, with biblatex version 3.10 (2017/12/19) and `biber` version 2.10, the sorting is performed correctly, i.e., `Å` comes after `Z` -- and, a fortiori, *not* between `E` and `G`.

Comment: Can you show us the `.blg` file and check your `biblatex` and Biber versions? It would also help to know your OS and your TeX distribution. In older versions Biber would give incorrect sorting with TeX live, but that should be fixed with Biber >= 2.8. The current version of `biblatex` is 3.10, Biber is at 2.10. For me (MikTeX on Win 10, `biblatex` 3.10, Biber 2.10) the MWE sorts as 'E' -> 'G' -> 'Å'.

Comment: BTW: If you use `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}` `sortlocale` is automatically set for Swedish sorting. (Note that there are several Swedish sorting rules with regards to V, W. So if you need more fine-grained control you might have to resort to `sortlocale` after all: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/164).

Comment: I am using sharelatex.com, not sure what version the website is using. That also means that I don't have access to the .blg file, correct? If I don't add the sortlocale=se the sorting puts W first, before A

Comment: Yes, shareLaTeX use an outdated version where the sorting bug is still present. So you will have to resort to work-arounds if you want to continue using this web service: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396126/35864

Comment: Thank you, adding sortname = {{zzzAhlstrom Par}}  serves as a workaround!

Comment: Great. Would you be OK with marking your question as a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: I agree that the answer is the same and refers to the same bug, but I were not able to find the other question using google. The questions are not perfect duplicates however. Your call.

Comment: Your question will remain searchable even if it is closed as a duplicate and it would not really make sense to just copy the answer, so I will vote to close.