# Bibliography order: How to get Danish letters æ, ø, å last

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting, scandinavian-letters

The Danish alphabet ends like  x, y, z, æ, ø, å, but in my biblatex bibliography, e.g. ø is treated like o, i.e. a name like Østergaard is listed between Nilsen ans Petersen. Is there a way to fix that?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.5cm, left=2.6cm,right=2.6cm,top=2.6cm,bottom=3cm, footskip=.67cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{xeCJK} 
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.5} 
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.3ex}
\setCJKmainfont{TakaoMincho}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{2mm} 
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{2mm} 
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{2mm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{2mm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true,style=authoryear-icomp,dashed=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
        or
        test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
    }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
    }
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite} %sets name order to last-first 
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
        {}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{csquotes} %for references
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @incollection{nohda2000,
        title = {Teaching by {{Open}}-{{Approach Method}} in {{Japanese Mathematics Classroom}}.},
        url = {http://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED466736},
        booktitle = {Proceedings of the 24th {{Conference}} of the {{International Group}} for the {{Psychology}} of {{Mathematics Education}}},
        urldate = {2017-04-02},
        date = {2000},
        author = {Nohda, Nobuhiko},
        file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/Q8GPK94B/Nohda - 2000 - Teaching by Open-Approach Method in Japanese Mathe.pdf}
    }
    @thesis{rasmussen2016a,
        title = {Praxeologies and {{Institutional Interactions}} in the {{Advanced Science Teacher Education}}},
        url = {http://www.ind.ku.dk/publikationer/inds_skriftserie/44/44-Klaus_Rasmussen.pdf},
        institution = {{Copenhagen}},
        urldate = {2016-09-13},
        date = {2016},
        author = {Rasmussen, Klaus},
        file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/VA58FM77/Rasmussen - 2016 - Praxeologies and Institutional Interactions in the.pdf}
    }
    @thesis{ostergaard2016,
        title = {Teori-Praksis-Problematikken i Matematiklæreruddannelsen - Belyst Gennem Lektionsstudier},
        url = {http://rudar.ruc.dk/bitstream/1800/28447/1/Teori_praksis_problematikken_i_matematikl_reruddannelse_Kaj_stergaard_Phd_afhandling_RUC.pdf},
        pagetotal = {322},
        urldate = {2016-08-04},
        date = {2016},
        author = {Østergaard, Kaj},
        file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/JREV3I9T/Østergaard - 2016 - Teori-praksis-problematikken i matematiklæreruddan.pdf}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}


\section*{Text}

\parencites{ostergaard2016}{rasmussen2016a}{nohda2000}

\section*{References} % REFERENCES  ---------------------------------
\sloppy
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong_bibliography_order]

Comment: What language setting do you use in your document? How do you input these characters? Do you use Biber? What version of `biblatex` and Biber do you use? Please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). There was a regression with sorting in older versions of Biber on TeX live, but with 2.8 and higher everything should sort correctly.

Comment: Please add a *full* MWE, not just code snippets. It is impossible to say what is going on with only these bits of code. For what it's worth the code you have shown so far should have absolutely no bearing on the matter of sorting. But you never know what else is going on in a document. If your document is set up for Danish language, sorting should be performed following these rules by Biber.

Comment: @moewe: thanks for your response. I am still trying to figure out how to do this in the best way, and while I appear to be a slow learning, I appreciate you educating me. I out-commented the three things illustrated above which led to no change. I've edited to add an MWEB

Comment: @jbahn:  You could use ` sortlocale = danish` as option for `biblatex`.

Comment: @leandriis: Unfortunately that changes nothing.

Comment: @jbahn, make sure you remove aux files. using `sortlocale=danish` does work for me.

Comment: @jbahn: Please also check which versions of `biber` and `biblatex` you are using. As already pointed out by moewe, sorting might not work as expected using older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @incollection{nohda2000,
        title = {Teaching by {{Open}}-{{Approach Method}} in {{Japanese Mathematics Classroom}}.},
        url = {http://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED466736},
        booktitle = {Proceedings of the 24th {{Conference}} of the {{International Group}} for the {{Psychology}} of {{Mathematics Education}}},
        urldate = {2017-04-02},
        date = {2000},
        author = {Nohda, Nobuhiko},
        file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/Q8GPK94B/Nohda - 2000 - Teaching by Open-Approach Method in Japanese Mathe.pdf}
    }
    @thesis{rasmussen2016a,
        title = {Praxeologies and {{Institutional Interactions}} in the {{Advanced Science Teacher Education}}},
        url = {http://www.ind.ku.dk/publikationer/inds_skriftserie/44/44-Klaus_Rasmussen.pdf},
        institution = {{Copenhagen}},
        urldate = {2016-09-13},
        date = {2016},
        author = {Rasmussen, Klaus},
        file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/VA58FM77/Rasmussen - 2016 - Praxeologies and Institutional Interactions in the.pdf}
    }
    @thesis{ostergaard2016,
        title = {Teori-Praksis-Problematikken i Matematiklæreruddannelsen - Belyst Gennem Lektionsstudier},
        url = {http://rudar.ruc.dk/bitstream/1800/28447/1/Teori_praksis_problematikken_i_matematikl_reruddannelse_Kaj_stergaard_Phd_afhandling_RUC.pdf},
        pagetotal = {322},
        urldate = {2016-08-04},
        date = {2016},
        author = {Østergaard, Kaj},
        file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/JREV3I9T/Østergaard - 2016 - Teori-praksis-problematikken i matematiklæreruddan.pdf},
        sort=ZO
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.5cm, left=2.6cm,right=2.6cm,top=2.6cm,bottom=3cm, footskip=.67cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,giveninits=true,style=authoryear-icomp,dashed=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=true, sortlocale=danish]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
        or
        test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
    }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
    }
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite} %sets name order to last-first 
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
        {}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}


\section*{Text}
\parencites{ostergaard2016}{rasmussen2016a}{nohda2000}

\section*{References} % REFERENCES  ---------------------------------
\sloppy
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

With the use of `biblatex`'s option `setlocale=danish` the above MWE results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: If the OP were to write in Danish, i.e. they used `\setdefaultlanguage{danish}`, then `biblatex` would automatically set `sortlocale=danish`. Since in the MWE we have `\setdefaultlanguage{english}`, the English sorting rules need to be overruled by an explicit `sortlocale=danish`.

Comment: If OP is writing an English text I'd actually suggest to keep the English sorting order. Few people outside of Scandinavia are familiar with the placement of the special Danish vowels and most will thus search Østergaard under "O" and not find the article if listed at the end of the alphabet.